# What does this lambda function do?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm still struggling with lambdas.  This code was submitted as an answer to [Python: closest coordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390370/python-closest-coordinate).  A lot of it confused me, but I've sorted through most of it.  The float method's use of `self` is still a little tricky for me (I get `self.x` and `self.y`, but not really sure what self is in that context).  Only mentioning that as it is likely involved in the main part I don't understand, which is the lambda function in the `closest` method.  I see it's going to return the minimum item generated, and that it unpacks the points as args.  Then I get a little lost.  Are `__sub__` and `__pow__` redefining `-` and `**` respectively, or are they just distinct methods?

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def closest(self,*points):           
        return min(points,key=lambda x:float(x-self))
    def __sub__(self,other):
        return Point((self.x-other.x) , (self.y - other.y))
    def __pow__(self,powTo):
        return Point(self.x**powTo,self.y**powTo) 
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y
    def __float__(self):
        return sum(self**2)**0.5
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s,%s)"%(self.x,self.y)

pt0 = Point(9,2)
print pt0.closest(Point(0,0),Point(10,0),Point(10,10))
```

Comment: have you tried printing self in closets or `print(self-points[1])`

Comment: `self` is the value that the method was called on, e.g. `pt0` when you use `pt0.closest(...)`.

Comment: The documentation of these special methods is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Comment: Awesome, thank you everybody.  I'll stand by my opinion that this was a kinda mean answer for the beginner-OP for the linked question, but for me, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda args: expr` is not a special magic feature, it's just nice shorthand for

```
def someFunc(args):
    return expr
```

which is mainly useful when you need a small function with a simple expression for its body and you don't care about the name.  If we used familiar syntax, the `closest()` method would be:

```
def closest(self,*points):
    def keyFunc(x):
        return float(x-self)           
    return min(points,key=keyFunc)
```

that is, it creates a small, one off function which does a little bit of calculation depending on `self` and its argument `x`, and passes that into the `min()` builtin function.  As Ostrea explains, `min(seq, key=f)` returns the item *x* in `seq` which minimizes `f(`*x*`)`

Answer (score 1):

[`def __sub__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) is one of the magic methods you can define on an object.

It will be called when you substract the two points. In the example, `self` will be `pt0`.

Comment: Update: [Same link for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). (NB: The correct word is "subtract", not "substract".)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `__sub__` and `__pow__` redefines `-` and `**` respectively. In this example you just pass anonymous function to optional argument for `min()`. Here is what this optional argument does, as said in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#min):

> The optional keyword-only key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort().

In this anonymous function you just subtract point, on which `closest` was called from points, which was passed as arguments and then convert it to float (this conversion is overridden, see `__float__`)