# Shortest distance between one point and a group of others?

Tags: python, function

I have a problem. I want to write a function in python which will receive a coordinate X and a group of coordinates S. I need to return the closest coordinate to x from group s. So when you call a function it will return this:

```
closest((9, 2), {(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10)}) # calling a function
(10, 0)
```

Because its the closest to both points. 
I already have a function which calculates the distance between two points

```
def distance(s,t):
    v = 0
    for i in range(len(t)):
        v = v+(s[i]-t[i])**2
    return (sqrt(v))
```

But now I'm stuck on how to return the closest tuple of coordinates to the one given in x. 
My English is not that good so if you do not understand my question, please say it and I will try to explain somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you can make a `distance` function that just returns the distance between two points

```
import math
def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p2[1] - p1[1])**2)
```

Then `closest` can use the `min` function with the `key` parameter to use your `distance` function with each element from `others`

```
def closest(pt, others):
    return min(others, key = lambda i: distance(pt, i))
```

Example

```
>>> closest((9, 2), {(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10)})
(10, 0)
```

To calculate the average distance

```
def avgDistance(pt, others):
    dists = [distance(pt, i) for i in others]
    return sum(dists) / len(dists)

>>> avgDistance((9, 2), {(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10)})
6.505956727697075
```

Comment: or use `functools.partial` like so: `key=partial(distance, pt)`.

Comment: @ch3ka That is also a good idea, that can at least remove the `lambda` expression to help readability

Comment: Python has a built-in 2D distance function, see [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html?highlight=hypot#math.hypot).

Comment: how would I get the average distance in function closest ? I mean I want to return average distance from x to all coordinates in group s ? so it will return something like this -> 
average((1, 1), {(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10)})
7.732506920622789

Comment: can't thank you enough. thank you.

Comment: one last question. I need a function which will return the point which has the smallest average distance. When you call the function it should return something like this. 
center({(0, 0), (10, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (5, 4)})
(5, 4)
I know I need to use the average function from before, I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: @user3083561, if you want to use Cyber's solution (which is correct), you'll have to call `avgDistance` for each point in your list, passing as the 2nd argument to that function the entire list without that element (or just the entire list, you'll only do 1 calculation too many). Then find the minimum of those average distances, together with the index of the node you've passed in. However, I encourage you to look into scipy and numpy.

Answer (score 5):

*Don't reinvent the wheel*. This functionality exists in python's scientific libraries ([scipy](http://docs.scipy.org)) and if you're going to be performing more mathematics on your data, you should really start using those libraries as they are much faster than doing it with regular python, because the code is *vectorized* and is often a thin wrapper to *optimized C/fortran libraries*.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
>>> a = np.array([[9, 2]])
>>> others = np.array([[0, 0], [10, 0], [10, 10]])
>>> def closest_point(pt, others):
...     distances = cdist(pt, others)
...     return others[distances.argmin()]
... 
>>> closest_point(a, others)
array([10,  0])
```

To compute the mean distance over all distances to that one point:

```
>>> distances = cdist(a, others)
>>> distances
array([[ 9.21954446,  2.23606798,  8.06225775]])
>>> distances.mean()
6.5059567276970753
```

Finally, to find the point that is "most centered", in the sense that it has the smallest average distance to all the others, you'll have to compute the distance between all nodes:

```
>>> all_nodes = np.array([[0,0], [10,0], [0,10], [10, 10], [5,4]])
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
>>> avg_dists = squareform(pdist(all_nodes)).mean(axis=1)
>>> avg_dists
array([ 8.10905197,  8.10905197,  8.39047706,  8.39047706,  5.68534957])
>>> all_nodes[avg_dists.argmin()]
array([5, 4])
```

Comment: I see I didn't write my question very correctly... Those points are defined when you call x,s from function AVERAGE, which is written in the first answer. Ugh, why do I suck at english I could explain it so much better...

Comment: @user3083561 Can you rephrase that? I don't understand what you mean. The points you've written about, are included in `all_nodes`, which is a matrix with 5 rows and 2 columns, each row being one of your points.